# Problems starting MySQL on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, macports

I am not able to start MySQL server on Mac OS X 10.4.11. MySQL was installed using Macports. MySQL was running fine until it suddenly died without any obvious reason.

When running "mysql", I get the error message:

```
 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through 
 socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

If I try to start MySQL manually, I get the following error message:

```
 sudo /opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/mysql.server start
 Starting MySQL/opt/local/share/mysql5/mysql/mysql.server: line
 159: kill: (636) - No such process
 ERROR!
```

In /etc/mysql/my.cnf I have:

```
 socket = __PREFIX/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

But the path "opt/local/var/run/mysqld/" does not exist on my system.

I tried to change the socket path to "__PREFIX/var/run/mysql5/ mysqld.sock" (which is where the socket is located). Unfortunately, this did not help either.

Owner and Permissions for /opt/local/var/run/mysql5/ are correctly set.

Any suggestions on how to start MySQL again? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What is the reason that made you install MySQL with macports? Why not using the native MacOS X installer? Furthermore, it seems more a ServerFault.com question

Comment: Maybe @Jon's Mac is a development machine. :-)

Comment: If `kill` fails: is there a PID file somewhere you can remove & try to start the server again? +1 for serverfault.com b.t.w.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Mac too and install MySQL from macports.  I have experienced the same WTF moments you describe, and I've had to resort to this solution to restart MySQL:

```
# launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
# launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
```

That seems wrong, too brute force.  But I haven't found a better solution yet.  I suggest searching ServerFault.com and see if someone else has a better method.  Please post here if you do find something.

@lacopo: Why use macports?  Because macports is really picky about dependencies.  If you use any macports tools that depend on MySQL, it's easier to install MySQL via macports.